# How to create source type image in python code?

Tags: python-3.x, obs

I am trying to create the source type image from python script in obs. Want to know proper steps to create source in script. I already checked, no proper doc for python scripting available.

```
obs.obs_source_create('banner-image','xyz')
obs.obs_source_create('banner-image','xyz')
```

Logs

> TypeError: obs_source_create() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

I want to create source type image from scrip & add that source to my current scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a simple FFI implementation, so try:

```
obs.obs_source_create('banner-image', 'xyz', None, None)
```

Source: First hit on Google when searching for `"obs_source_create"`:

- https://obsproject.com/docs/reference-sources.html

Excerpt:

> ```
> obs_source_t *obs_source_create(const char *id, const char *name, obs_data_t *settings, obs_data_t *hotkey_data)
> ```
>
> Creates a source of the specified type with the specified settings.
>
> The “source” context is used for anything related to presenting or modifying video/audio. Use obs_source_release to release it.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - id – The source type string identifier
> - name – The desired name of the source. If this is not unique, it will be made to be unique
> - settings – The settings for the source, or NULL if none
> - hotkey_data – Saved hotkey data for the source, or NULL if none
>
> Returns:
>
> - A reference to the newly created source, or NULL if failed